# Static Variables - C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, static, scope

I am writing a program that shares a globaly declared pointer to a buffer that could be used by all the functions within the program. But the buffer is not necessary in certain cases so the pointer is left NULL until it is initaly allocated by evualting it's NULL status. I also need a globaly declared integer to prevent against buffer overflows and to reallocate if necessary. Just because I am writing this program for practice I want the buffer size integer to be declared staticly when the buffer is allocated. For example this code segment would allocate the inital memory size for the buffer.

```
static char *buffer //(Globaly Declared) I know that the static part is implied I just want to put emphasis on it.

while(program has arguments to do)//Not actual code. I put this here to give an idea of where the statement is located
{
   //None relavant code here..


    if(buffer is necessary)//Not actual code. I put this here to give an idea of where the statement is located
    {
          if(buffer == NULL)
          {
             static unsigned int initial_value = 64;
             static unsigned int *buffer_size = &inital_value;

              if( (buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*inital_value+1)) == NULL)
              {
                 perror("MALLOC ERROR");
                 return 1;
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

I have a few questions about how this works(if it does) and how static memory in general works.

- I know that static variables have a life span of the entire program execution time but unless they are globaly declared they have a limited scope as well. So my assumption is that a pointer is needed to keep track of the static memory location but does the pointer need to be static aswell?
- When will the memory be staticly allocated? When the if statment is true or will the variable simply be allocated when the program starts(like global variables)
- Is deallocation of the variable handeled for me? What should I do if a pointer is just declared staticly but the memory it points to is actually allocated dynamically (for example my buffer(static char *buffer)).
- Also these may sound like a stupid questions but is the unsigned part of the integer pointer declaration necessary, do I need to write (inital_value+1) or can i just write inital_value+1(I dont think it matters here because sizeof(char) is one so allocation size could be rewritten as 1*64+1) and do terminating NULL bytes need to be the same type(size) as the rest of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer is statically allocated, but the memory it points to is dynamically allocated, only when your if conditional holds true.

Deallocation of the "variable" (the pointer) is handled for you, but deallocation of the memory it points to is not handled for you.  You will need to `free` anything you `malloc`.

You're right that you could write (initial_value+1) or initial_value + 1.  The terminating NULL byte does need to be the same size (byte / char) as the rest of the array.  In C, all array elements are the same size. You may find (initial_value+1) better reflects that.

Answer (score 1):

```
static unsigned int initial_value = 64;
static unsigned int *buffer_size = &inital_value;
```

Both will be initialized only once on the first execution and they are located on the global memory, within the scope derived by `{}`.